# How can one develop a chrome extension that accesses google drive?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api

Is there any examples of a chrome extension that accesses drive?

Using [chrome_ex_oauth.js](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/extensions/oauth_contacts/chrome_ex_oauth.js?content-type=text/plain):

It dances with the docs list scope (`https://docs.google.com/feeds/`), but the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` scope doesn't seem to work. I've tried changing consumer keys/secrets, et cetera:

```
oauth =  ChromeExOAuth.initBackgroundPage({
  'request_url': 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken',
  'authorize_url': 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken',
  'access_url': 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken',
  'consumer_key': 'anonymous',
  'consumer_secret': 'anonymous',
  'scope':'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
  'app_name': 'Chrome Extension'
});

oauth.authorize(onAuthorizeCallback);
```

If you can get me past oauth, I'm sure I can handle the rest.

Comment: The redirect page hangs with GET chrome-extension://invalid/chrome_ex_oauth.js  chrome-extension://invalid/:16
GET chrome-extension://invalid/chrome_ex_oauthsimple.js  chrome-extension://invalid/:16
GET chrome-extension://invalid/chrome_ex_oauth_init.js  chrome-extension://invalid/:16

Comment: At one point i actually got it to call onAuthorizeCallback with a token..... Working from the [oauth tutorial](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_oauth.html) again just to be sure. Checked out https://src.chromium.org/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/extensions/oauth_contacts. The gdocs sample fails due script permissions. The oauth example fails the same as above. Loading the extensions unpacked.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, there are prerequisites before this can work. See this : https://developers.google.com/drive/get-started#create_a_new_file_from_the_drive_ui and more specifically [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/register) and [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/listing).